# Hide Hyperlink if field is NULL - Classic ASP

Tags: asp-classic, ado

I am now back in classic ASP and want to hide a hyperlink that has a null value. This hyperlink is carrying over an ID to details view. If the details (field: highlights) is null, hide the hyperlink. I only want the hyperlinks to appear if a highlight exists.

I have the following code, but I don't know how to integrate this. I just completed this in ASP.NET, but I'm confused about how to get this in Classic ASP. Any suggestions would be greatly appreciated:

```
               if objRS.recordcount = 0 then
                  response.write "<p>Check back soon.</p>"
              else

               do while not objRS.eof

                ' Display Table Data
                  response.write "<td><a href='highlights.asp?ID=" & objRS.fields("ID") & "'>Read Highlights</a></td>"

                ' Loop it
                    objRS.movenext
                  loop
                    response.write "</table>"   

              end if
```

Previously in .NET, I was doing the following:

```
<asp:PlaceHolder ID="PlaceHolder2" runat="server" Visible='<%# IIf((Eval("Highlights")).ToString().Length > 0, "true", "false") %>'>
    <h3>Read Highlights</h3>
    <asp:Label ID="highlights" runat="server" Text='<%# Bind("Highlights") %>'></asp:Label>
</asp:PlaceHolder>
```

Not sure if I'm on the right right or way wrong track here, well it didn't work...says object is required...

```
If objRS.fields("Highlights") Is Not Null Then
   response.write "<td><a href='highlights.asp?ID=" & objRS.fields("ID") & "'>Read Highlights</a></td>"
End if
```

Trying this too:

```
If objRS.fields("Highlights") = NULL Then
  response.write "<td>&nbsp;</td>"
Else 
  response.write "<td><a href='highlights.asp?ID=" & objRS.fields("ID") & "'>Read Highlights</a></td>"
End if
```

Got it here:
Note: the code is not pasting with format, looks sorta messy

```
If Not (IsNull(objRS("Highlights"))) Then response.write "<td><a href='highlights.asp?ID=" & objRS.fields("ID") & "'>Read Highlights</a></td>" Else response.write "<td>&nbsp;</td>" End if
```

Comment: Test if objRS.fields("ID") is null or blank

Comment: It will always have an ID because that is automatically generated...The ID is the field making the correct "Highlights" show on the details page.

Comment: Hmmm, how can I too add If Not "empty"...it may not be NULL, but the field may actually be empty too...

Comment: If Not (IsNull(objRS("Highlights")) and objRS("Highlights") <> "")

Comment: Thanks Tim. I understand your logic, but this didn't work. I'm thinking something is off just slightly...perhaps the quotes or grouping of parenthesis?

Comment: Sorry, my VB is nasty rusty. It might be (not isnull(objRS("Highlights"))) and (not objRS("Highlights") <> "")

Answer (score 1):

The null operator in VBScript is called `Nothing`

```
If objRS.fields("Highlights") is Nothing or  Then
  response.write "<td>&nbsp;</td>"
Else 
  response.write "<td><a href='highlights.asp?ID=" & objRS.fields("ID") & "'>Read Highlights</a></td>"
End if
```

**Edit:** but if you have to test if the field is empty or null, I have this function always handy:

```
function IsEmpty(f)
    IsEmpty = IsNull(f) or trim(f) = ""
end function
```

So your code will be:

```
If IsEmpty(objRS.fields("Highlights")) Then
  response.write "<td>&nbsp;</td>"
Else 
  response.write "<td><a href='highlights.asp?ID=" & objRS.fields("ID") & "'>Read Highlights</a></td>"
End if
```

Comment: Thanks Eduardo! I'll give this a try tomorrow when I have a bit more time to try some code. I appreciate your help.

Answer (score 0):

```
if objRS.recordcount = 0 then
                  response.write "<p>Check back soon.</p>"
              else

               do while not objRS.eof

                ' Display Table Data
IF NOT ISNULL(objRS.fields("Highlights")) AND objRS.fields("Highlights") <> "" THEN
                  response.write "<td><a href='highlights.asp?ID=" & objRS.fields("ID") & "'>Read Highlights</a></td>"
END IF

                ' Loop it
                    objRS.movenext
                  loop
                    response.write "</table>"   

              end if
```